# Express 4 app doesn't work in Azure when deployed via Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, azure, express, visual-studio-2017

I have a node js express app generated from Visual Studio 2017 Basic Azure Node.js Express Application. I assume all the configuration required for Azure deployment is set in the Web.config file that comes with the template, but i am getting this error after Azure publish:

> iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.
>   HRESULT: 0x2 HTTP status: 500 HTTP subStatus: 1002 HTTP reason:
>   Internal Server Error You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because
>   system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is
>   'true'.
>
> In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process,
>   consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the
>   problem.
>
> The node.exe process has not written any information to stderr or
>   iisnode was unable to capture this information. Frequent reason is
>   that the iisnode module is unable to create a log file to capture
>   stdout and stderr output from node.exe. Please check that the identity
>   of the IIS application pool running the node.js application has read
>   and write access permissions to the directory on the server where the
>   node.js application is located. Alternatively you can disable logging
>   by setting system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled element of
>   web.config to 'false'.

If i publish the app without modifying anything, it works well, but the moment i add my static files, and add relevant modules, it starts giving me the error above. Below is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your Node.js application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=290972
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!--
    <add key="StorageAccountName" value="" />
    <add key="StorageAccountKey" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusNamespace" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusIssuerName" value="" />
    <add key="ServiceBusIssuerSecretKey" value="" />
    -->
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- mimeMap enables IIS to serve particular file types as specified by fileExtension. -->
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />

    <!-- Web.Debug.config adds attributes to this to enable remote debugging when publishing in Debug configuration. -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.pug"/>

    <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Comment out iisnode above, and uncomment iisnode below. -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.pug"
      loggingEnabled="true"
      devErrorsEnabled="true"
      nodeProcessCommandLine="node.exe &#45;&#45;debug"/>-->

    <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a Node.js application 
    to be handled by the iisnode module -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />

      <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Uncomment NtvsDebugProxy handler below.
      Additionally copy Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole to 'bin' from the Remote Debug Proxy folder.-->
      <!--<add name="NtvsDebugProxy" path="ntvs-debug-proxy/67499f58-9ba1-441d-b23f-6d860606ddb5" verb="*" resourceType="Unspecified"
        type="Microsoft.NodejsTools.Debugger.WebSocketProxy, Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole"/>-->
    </handlers>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Uncomment the NtvsDebugProxy rule below. --> 
        <!--<rule name="NtvsDebugProxy" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> 
          <match url="^ntvs-debug-proxy/.*"/> 
        </rule>--> 

        <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

  <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): uncomment system.web below --> 
  <!--<system.web> 
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/> 
    <customErrors mode="Off"/> 
  </system.web>--> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you are using the listen address provided by the iisnode module through the `process.env.PORT` environment variable. See [Nodejs application returns error: iisnode encountered an error when processing the request HRESULT: 0x2 HTTP status: 500 HTTP subStatus: 1002](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214028809-Nodejs-application-returns-error-iisnode-encountered-an-error-when-processing-the-request-HRESULT-0x2-HTTP-status-500-HTTP-subStatus-1002).

For further troubleshooting, you can enable the logging of stdout and stderr streams. About how to do that please refer to [How to debug a Node.js web app in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-debug).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already have `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 443);`

`var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});` Will enable remote debugging as you suggested.

Comment: Easy fix with remote debugging enabled. Thanks